# How to take a vector input in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, input

I m trying to take a vector input from keyboard. For example, If I enter `1 2 3`. then I have a vector `x = [1, 2, 3]`.

I found a solution [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-take-N-number-of-an-input-array-in-Python-3), which is

```
# If the numbers are provided in same line then you can use,

x = list(map(int, input().split()))

# If inputs are in different lines then,

x = [ int(input()) for i in range(n)]
```

I try the first line of code `arr = list(map(int, input().split()))`, but it returns an error `RuntimeError: Evaluation error: argument "prompt" is missing, with no default`.

Could you please explain how to resolve this problem?

Update:

1. The code `x = list(map(int, input().split()))` runs fine in Jupyter notebook:

[image]

2. The code `x = list(map(int, input().split()))` returns error when I use R notebook:

[image]

3. The code `x = list(map(int, input('Input here').split()))` runs fine I use R notebook:

[image]

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I use distribution Anaconda 2020.02 and my Python is 3.7.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I added a screenshot for clarity.

Comment: Hi @BrendanA.  I added an update in my question. It seems that running this code line in R notebook is problematic.

Comment: I don't know much about R Notebooks, but it looks like for some reason it's treating the optional prompt argument as required. If you really don't want any text there the easiest solution would be `list(map(int, input('').split()))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: while this fixed the specific example above, input doesn't require a prompt

The input() function requires a prompt as an argument, to show to the user. You just need to fill it in, for example `input("Enter a vector")`

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp

Comment: But... in your link, the first example is using it without, so what does that goes to show?

Comment: But it works perfectly fine when I add prompt :) 1+

Comment: @Crush_on_You The `prompt` argument of `input` is optional and an empty `input()` would work perfectly fine. Your issue is something different